# I want to not allow typing other characters in the input field

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, input

I have a form and I need to fill it with numbers only and I want to not allow typing other characters in the input field using JavaScript.

I need a solution in JavaScript.

Comment: Why don't you use `<input type="number">`?

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I want to learn how to do it using JavaScript.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, ***[search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+allow+only+numbers+in+text+field+site:stackoverflow.com)***; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can replace all non-digit characters on the "input" event.

For example:

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
});
```

```html
<input>
```

Comment: This is a MASSIVE dupe!